# Iterating through an array inside a conditional && statement in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, checkbox

I have an array:

```
console.log(tenantArray)
(8) ["WeWork", "Regus", "Spaces", "Knotel", "RocketSpace", "HQ Global Workspaces", "Other", "Select All"]
```

I also have a large data object, which I want to filter using d3, using a checkbox. The filter will be based on two conditions, the "Agency_Bro" property, and whether or not the "Tenant" property matches any of the strings in the tenantArray listed above.  In this sense, the "tenantArray" array above is just a dummy used for string matching purposes. Both conditions have to be true for filter.

The filter works fine if it just reads:

```
d3.selectAll("#JLLCheckbox").on("change", function() {

            var type = "JLL"            
            display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
            d3.selectAll(".features")
            .filter(function(d) { 
                return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type             
            })
            .attr("display", display);
});
```

However, when I try to add in both conditional statements, the checkbox stops working (no data filtered) yet no error message occurs.

```
d3.selectAll("#JLLCheckbox").on("change", function() {

    var type = "JLL"            
    display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";

    d3.selectAll(".features")
        .filter(function(d) { 
            return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type &&
                    tenantArray.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if (d.properties.Tenant === entry){
                        return d.properties.Tenant
                    }
                    });         
        })
});
```

Two questions:  any reason the above logic is failing?  And, is there a more efficient way to do this, without going through the trouble of the array?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) prototype doesn't return anything, but you're using it as part of a condition inside your filter, i'm pretty sure anything `&& undefined` will return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better replace `forEach` with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to receive a `true/false` value:

```
d3.selectAll("#JLLCheckbox").on("change", function() {

  var type = "JLL"
  display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";

  d3.selectAll(".features")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type &&
        tenantArray.some(function(entry) {
          return d.properties.Tenant === entry;
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!   It's working now.  But one question: what exactly is the 'some' method doing in this scenario?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12, happy to help. The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. In this case the test is `d.properties.Tenant === entry`.

Comment: Awesome.  That's exactly what I was looking for, but wasn't aware the some() method existed.  Thanks again.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I'm not sure why you went with this as `indexOf()` works just as well and reduces the amount of code, but hey it's your choice.

Comment: @RyanWilson, probably because `entry` is `undefined` in your example?

Comment: @KoshVery It's not undefined, I just condensed my answer to the line in question. I see no reason to copy a bunch of the OP's code into my answer that I am not modifying

Comment: @RyanWilson, please look once again. it's definitely undefined.

Comment: @KoshVery Obviously you don't understand my comment. Have a good one.

Comment: er.. sorry.  I thought I could check both answers here.  My bad.  Thank you all again.

Answer (score 4):

Change to this, you can use `indexOf()` on your array to see if the value is contained inside and if not return false:

```
return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type &&
   tenantArray.indexOf(d.properties.Tenant) > -1; //Does a boolean check if indexOf() 
   //returns a value greater than -1, which means the value was found in your array
});
```

Documentation of `indexOf` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @RyanWilson, appreciate your help!  Your answer was helpful as well, and I plan on testing both methods further.

Comment: Check it again.